# Server Shutdown windows server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

One of my client is still using a windows server 2003 and wants to grant "shutdown " rights to remote user ,who's local login rights are denied .Is it possible ? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can grant shutdown rights (or any other rights, actually) to any local or domain user (or group) by modifying the local security policy, in the "User Rights Assignment" section: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221963(v=ws.11).aspx; you can also modify the same settings using a GPO. Shutdown rights are distinct from log on rights, thus it's perfectly possible to grant one and deny another.

However, since you are explicitly mentioning users which don't have local log on rights, the computer will need to be a domain member, and the users will need to be domain users, in order to be able to log on somewhere else in the network and run remote commands against this specific system (such as `shutdown.exe`).

This also applies to later Windows operating systems, it's not specific to Windows Server 2003.